# jQuery trigger onDrop event react node

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Is there any known method how to trigger the drop event from React via jQuery?

There seems to be little documentation about this topic, in general you should avoid using both but lets assume in this case it just makes sense.

I tried so far this, but the event seems to not receive on reactside.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".draggable").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $(".droppable").droppable({
    accept: ".draggable",
    classes: {
      "ui-droppable-active": "ui-state-active",
      "ui-droppable-hover": "ui-state-hover"
    },
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
      event.initEvent("drop", true, true);
      $(this)[0].dispatchEvent(event);
      console.log("works as designed");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just finished implementing jQuery UI's drag-n-drop functionality, with .draggable() and .droppable(), in React.  As you pointed out, you wouldn't normally want to do this, but sometimes it's the best tool for the job.

Your question doesn't entirely make sense to me.  The drop event triggers when the .draggable() *jQuery-managed* element is dropped onto the .droppable() *jQuery-managed* element.  So when you say that you want to "trigger the drop event from reactjs via jQuery", do you mean that you want to call the same function that *jQuery* uses when it drops the item, but you want to call that event from within *React*??  Or are you just trying to say that you want to use jQuery's drag-n-drop functions inside React??  Because those aren't the same thing.  I'm going to assume that you're just trying to call jQuery's drag-n-drop features from within React.

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/draggable';
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/droppable';
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
    setDroppable() {
      const reactComponent = this;
      $('.roleListItems').droppable({
          drop : function(event, ui) {
              const roleId = event.target.getAttribute('roleid');
              const userId = ui.draggable[0].getAttribute('userid');
              if (!reactComponent.roleUserExists(roleId, userId)) { session.ListOfRolesCarousel.callCreateRoleUser(roleId,  userId); }
              else { reactComponent.setSelectedRoleId(roleId, true); }
          },
          tolerance : 'touch',
      });
    }
    setDraggable() {
      const grabbingCursor = this.grabbingCursor;
      $('.userListItems').draggable({
         appendTo : document.getElementById('rolesContainer'),
         helper : 'clone',
         revert : 'invalid',
         snap : '.roleListItems',
         snapMode : 'inner',
         snapTolerance : 25,
         start : function(event, ui) {
            ui.helper[0].style.cursor = grabbingCursor;
            ui.helper[0].style.width = $('#rolesContainer').width() + 'px';
         },
      });
    }
}
```

Here I'm:

- Importing jQuery, as well as the draggable and droppable widgets
- Inside .droppable(), I'm grabbing the values that I need from the dropped element (in this case, it's the roleId and the userId)
- Then I call React functions/methods to process those values
- **Notice** that I had to create a variable called *reactComponent* and set it to *this* so I could call the React method from inside the drop() function.  This is necessary because *this* has a different meaning once you're inside jQuery's drop() method.

Comment: Thanks for responding so quick! Actually I want jQuery only to trigger the event from "outside"-react. It should only tell the corresponding node that there is a event fired, with some data parameters. This is because part of my UI cannot be replaced and those are written with jQuery.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you're saying that jQuery is running completely outside of React?  And when the drop() function fires, you want a node (component) from inside React to listen to that event and act accordingly??

Comment: excatly what i m looking for!

Comment: At its core, React is still just Javascript, even if it feels a little "fancier".  So inside your React component, you can still use "standard" JS to add an event listener to the "drop" event.  Here you can see how to listen for the drop event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drop.  And here you can see an example of how you could hook that up to a React method/function inside a React component: https://appendto.com/2017/01/react-events-101/

Comment: this is what i have understood as well, however things are getting complicated since react works the way that it adds/removes/recycles DOM elements depending on how the content changes. So from jQuery perspective i would not know if an element was completely renewed at all (so the event listener is not existent for the new element)

Comment: This is why you need to have one framework that is the "system of record", meaning that one framework should be trusted to do the *real* work and, if you must use the other framework at the same time, that second framework should only be used for ancillary functionality.  If you have an app that is, basically, a jQuery app with a few React components thrown in here-or-there for ad hoc functionality, then you should be triggering the events - and listening for those events - in jQuery.

Comment: If you have a React app that needs a sprinkling of jQuery thrown in here-or-there, you should be trusting React to do all the heavy lifting.  I've shown the example of how to make that work above.  But, as you see, it's highly unmanageable to use two frameworks, at the same time, and expect them to continually pass information between them.

Comment: Also, notice that in my example above, I'm *cloning the element as a helper*.  This is significant, because I'm really not using jQuery at all to move/reorder DOM elements on the page.  I'm spawning a clone, which only serves as a marker to show where the user has dragged it to somewhere else.  When the drop happens, the temporary clone disappears *and I use React to dynamically update the onscreen display.*